# Make movement more smooth on Java Script Game | JavaScript Canvas

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas, html5-canvas, keylistener

I am working on very simple java script game. there's a falling random object (trash) and another object for catch the falling object (trash bin). everything seems fine but i wanted to make the movement of the trash bin more smooth. Do you have any idea to fix this? Thanks in Advance

this is my code

```
window.onload = function(){

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var canvasBack = document.getElementById("backgroundCanvas");
var contextBack = canvasBack.getContext("2d");

var timer;
//mengatur hiscore
var hiscore = 0;

//Background image, musik and arrays musik.
var background = new Image();
background.src = 'assets/bgw2.jpg';
var catchSounds = [];
var catchSoundCounter = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    var catchSound = new Audio();
    catchSound.src = 'Audio/bleep.wav';
    catchSounds.push(catchSound);
}

var music = new Audio();
music.src = 'Audio/MarimbaBoy.wav';
music.loop = true;

var smashSounds = [];
var smashCounter = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    var smash = new Audio();
    smash.src = 'Audio/smash.mp3';
    smashSounds.push(smash);
}

var player;
var fruits = [];
var numberOfFruits = 15;

//Player constructor
function Player()
{
    this.gameOver = false;
    this.score = 0;
    this.fruitsCollected = 0;
    this.fruitsMissed = 0;
    this.playerWidth = 150;
    this.playerHeight = 90;
    this.playerSpeed = 10;
    this.x = canvas.width / 2;
    this.y = canvas.height - this.playerHeight;
    this.playerImage = new Image();
    this.playerImage.src = 'assets/binn.png';

    //Draws the player
    this.render = function()
    {
        context.drawImage(this.playerImage, this.x, this.y);
    }

    //Moves the player left
    this.moveLeft = function()
    {
        if(this.x > 0)
        {
            this.x -= this.playerSpeed;
        }
    }

    //Moves the player right
    this.moveRight = function()
    {
        if(this.x < canvas.width - this.playerWidth)
        {
            this.x += this.playerSpeed;
        }
    }
}

//Fruit constructor
function Fruit()
{
    this.fruitNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    this.fruitType = "";
    this.fruitScore = 0;
    this.fruitWidth = 50;
    this.fruitHeight = 50;
    this.fruitImage = new Image();
    this.fruitSpeed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2 + 1);
    this.x = Math.random() * (canvas.width - this.fruitWidth);
    this.y = Math.random() * -canvas.height - this.fruitHeight;

    //Creates a different kind of fruit depending on the fruit number
    //which is generated randomly
    this.chooseFruit = function()
    {
        if(this.fruitNumber == 0)
        {
            this.fruitType = "pisang";
            this.fruitScore = 5 * this.fruitSpeed;
            this.fruitImage.src = 'assets/pisang.png';
        }
        else if(this.fruitNumber == 1)
        {
            this.fruitType = "rubbish";
            this.fruitScore = 10 * this.fruitSpeed;
            this.fruitImage.src = 'assets/rubbish.png';
        }
        else if(this.fruitNumber == 2)
        {
            this.fruitType = "botol";
            this.fruitScore = 15 * this.fruitSpeed;
            this.fruitImage.src = 'assets/botol.png';
        }
        else if(this.fruitNumber == 3)
        {
            this.fruitType = "coke";
            this.fruitScore = 20 * this.fruitSpeed;
            this.fruitImage.src = 'assets/coke.png';
        }
        else if(this.fruitNumber == 4)
        {
            this.fruitType = "apple";
            this.fruitScore = 25 * this.fruitSpeed;
            this.fruitImage.src = 'assets/apple.png';
        }
        else if(this.fruitNumber == 5)
        {
            this.fruitType = "papikra";
            this.fruitScore = 30 * this.fruitSpeed;
            this.fruitImage.src = 'assets/papikra.png';
        }
    }

    //Makes the fruit descend.
    //While falling checks if the fruit has been caught by the player
    //Or if it hit the floor.
    this.fall = function()
    {
        if(this.y < canvas.height - this.fruitHeight)
        {
            this.y += this.fruitSpeed;
        }
        else
        {
            smashSounds[smashCounter].play();
            if(smashCounter == 4)
            {
                smashCounter = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                smashCounter++;
            }

            player.fruitsMissed += 1;
            this.changeState();
            this.chooseFruit();
        }
        this.checkIfCaught();
    }

    //Checks if the fruit has been caught by the player
    //If it is caught, the player score and fruit counter is increased, and
    //the current fruit changes its state and becomes a different fruit.
    this.checkIfCaught = function()
    {
        if(this.y >= player.y)
        {
            if((this.x > player.x && this.x < (player.x + player.playerWidth)) ||
              (this.x + this.fruitWidth > player.x && this.x + this.fruitWidth < (player.x + player.playerWidth)))
            {
                catchSounds[catchSoundCounter].play();
                if(catchSoundCounter == 4)
                {
                    catchSoundCounter = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    catchSoundCounter++;
                }

                player.score += this.fruitScore;
                player.fruitsCollected += 1;

                this.changeState();
                this.chooseFruit();
            }
        }
    }

    //Randomly updates the fruit speed, fruit number, which defines the type of fruit
    //And also changes its x and y position on the canvas.
    this.changeState = function()
    {
        this.fruitNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
        this.fruitSpeed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2 + 1);
        this.x = Math.random() * (canvas.width - this.fruitWidth);
        this.y = Math.random() * -canvas.height - this.fruitHeight;
    }

    //Draws the fruit.
    this.render = function()
    {
        context.drawImage(this.fruitImage, this.x, this.y);
    }
}

//Adds controls. Left arrow to move left, right arrow to move right.
//ENTER to restart only works at the game over screen.
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){

 e.preventDefault();

    if(e.keyCode == 37)
    {
        player.moveLeft();
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 39)
    {
        player.moveRight();
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 13 && player.gameOver == true)
    {
        main();
        window.clearTimeout(timer);
    }
 });

main();

//Fills an array of fruits, creates a player and starts the game
function main()
{
    contextBack.font = "bold 20px Dominique";
    contextBack.fillStyle = "WHITE";
    player = new Player();
    fruits = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < numberOfFruits; i++)
    {
        var fruit = new Fruit();
        fruit.chooseFruit();
        fruits.push(fruit);
    }

    startGame();
}

function startGame()
{
    updateGame();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(drawGame);
}

//Checks for gameOver and makes each fruit in the array fall down.
function updateGame()
{
    music.play();
    if(player.fruitsMissed >= 10)
    {
        player.gameOver = true;
    }

    for(var j = 0; j < fruits.length; j++)
    {
        fruits[j].fall();
    }
    timer = window.setTimeout(updateGame, 30);
}

//Draws the player and fruits on the screen as well as info in the HUD.
function drawGame()
{
    if(player.gameOver == false)
    {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        contextBack.clearRect(0, 0, canvasBack.width, canvasBack.height);

        contextBack.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
        player.render();

        for(var j = 0; j < fruits.length; j++)
        {
            fruits[j].render();
        }
        contextBack.fillText("SCORE: " + player.score, 30, 50);
        contextBack.fillText("HIGHEST SCORE: " + hiscore, 140, 50);
        contextBack.fillText("FRUIT CAUGHT: " + player.fruitsCollected, 320, 50);
        contextBack.fillText("FRUIT MISSED: " + player.fruitsMissed, 490, 50);
    }
    else
    {
        //Different screen for game over.
        for(var i = 0; i < numberOfFruits; i++)
        {
            console.log("Speed was" + fruits[fruits.length - 1].fruitSpeed);
            fruits.pop();
        }

        if(hiscore < player.score)
        {
            hiscore = player.score;
            contextBack.fillText("NEW HI SCORE: " + hiscore, (canvas.width / 2) - 80, canvas.height / 2);
        }
        contextBack.fillText("PRESS ENTER TO RESTART", (canvas.width / 2) - 100, canvas.height / 2 + 50);
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(drawGame);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, just use one `requestAnimationFrame` and no other `setTimeout` code. These can start to run out of sync with each other and it's hard to pause them all when the player wants to pause the game.

Instead, use a counter instead of timeout.

```
let fruitCounter = 0

function drawGame() {
     // all your draw code here
     ...
     // every 60 frames drop a new fruit
     fruitCounter++
     if(fruitCounter > 60){
         fruitCounter = 0
         dropNewFruit()
     }

     // request the new frame unless its game over
     if(!gameOver) {
          requestAnimationFrame(drawGame)
     }
}
```

Also, if you use keyboard events like this, it will always be choppy because there is a delay when typing on the keyboard (just press a letter for a long time in a text field, you will see that it takes a while until more letters appear)

You can fix this by setting a variable once a key gets pressed.

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 37){
        moveLeft = 1
    }
}

window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 37){
        moveLeft = 0
    }
}
```

Then, you can use that variable in your animation code

```
function drawGame() {
     // all your draw code here
     player.x += moveLeft
     // request the new frame unless its game over
     if(!gameOver) {
          requestAnimationFrame(drawGame)
     }
}
```

These are just a few tips! This has always worked for me when I build a javascript game.

Comment: omg, thank you for your answer. hope it work for me too. have a nice day